# Python requests

Tags: python, django

Can we consume an API, for example use the POST method to retrieve products. Note that we pass the security key in the body or data. it's possible ??

```
def api(request):
url = 'https://datausa.io/api/data?product'

x = requests.post(url,data={'securityKey':'valueKey')
contenu=x.text
return HttpResponse(contenu)
```

Comment: Of course it's possible. The question is whether you're doing it correctly. Check API's documentation on to how properly pass the auth key - it's usually done in auth header, not request's body + your body is not encoded + you don't have content headers.

Comment: you're doing it in correct way. just fetch this in you api function
`securityKey= request.POST["securityKey"]`

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use the POST method by passing it a security key in the headers to simply retrieve the product data
I have an http 400 error
here is the code

```
def api(request):
  headers={'content-type':'application/json','security-key':'value-key'} 
  url = 'http://api-content/product/GetProduct'

  x = requests.post(url, headers = headers)
  content=x.status_code
  return HttpResponse(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course !

Most people use the requests library because it removes a lot of boilerplate and it is a really well built and maintained library : https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It is as easy as doing that :

```
r = requests.get('https://datausa.io/api/data?product')
r.status_code
200
r.headers = {'security-key': 'valuekey'}
```

You can also use Django Rest Framework with the authentification mechanism so you can use token to consume your api : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Comment: I have a 400 error now, when I put the key in the headers

Comment: This is not how you add the header. You added it after the header after the request was already processed. It should be added in the get call